# The meaning of "Need not hold" in Monotone convergence theorem for decreasing sequences

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am reading something on Monotone convergence Theorem and I came across this statement "MCT Need not hold for decreasing sequence of functions",

My concern is not with the counterexample given under the statement but the language used here.
Does this mean the same thing as " MCT doesn't always hold for decreasing sequence of functions"?

In which case I will take it to  mean that, It can actually hold for some decreasing sequences of functions but not always so.

Because I was thinking about this counterexample, consider the sequence of mble functons
 $$f_n=\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$$

on $[0,1] $, clearly $f_n$ is a decreasing sequence

I could say $|f_n|\leq 1, \forall n$ and $f_n\to 0$ pointwise a.e, Hence I can apply Lebesgue Dominated convergence Theorem.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_n=\int 0$$

I'm not sure if it's also okay to say,
 redefining $$h_n=1-f_n$$
we get an increasing sequence with $h_n\to 1$ and this satisfies MCT even though $f_n$ is decreasing.
and $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int h_n=\int 1$$

Comment: Yes, "need not hold" means "can fail".

Comment: Actually, "need not hold" is the same as "fails"

Comment: Re-check what the "Dominated" part of the theorem is about.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, As per Royden's definition, the requirements for  the dorminating function are that it should be measurable and integrable in the space. and since $g=1$ satisfies both conditions I though it could be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A statement that "Property A needs not hold for objects B" means that, there **exists** object B such that property A fails to hold. It does **not** mean that for all object B, property A does not hold.

So yes you can find an example of decreasing sequence that MCT does not hold, and you may also find an example of decreasing sequence that MCT actually holds.

Comment: A very concise answer and straight to the point , Thank you.
How about the ideas I presented, are they meaningful ?